# get Data by document name in Firestore

Tags: firebase, for-loop, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

I want to get specific data of Documents by the name of the document.

Here is the code:-

```
QuerySnapshot snaps =
   await Firestore.instance.collection(gender+'-names').getDocuments();
 for (int count; count < countOfLetters; count++) {
        nameID = letterCode+'-'+random.toString();
        name.add(snaps.documents[<<i want nameID here>>]['name']);
}
```

If someone can help me it would be great!

Comment: What is your question?  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: only document ID can place in there but I want to get from the Document name
It gives error when i add there a string